# How to lock GNOME3 on OpenBSD?

Tags: gnome3, openbsd

There is a normal user, that I added sudo permission to "zzz" on an OpenBSD 5.6 notebook. The "zzz" works, the notebook suspends.. but the GNOME 3 screensaver doesn't lock before/after suspend.

How can I suspend the notebook with screen locking?